# Copying entire row using Instr

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

Hi im wanting to loop through each row in my spreadsheet and for each instance it finds the word "North East" to copy that row into the North East sheet. This will be repeated on a weekly basis and therefore i need the script to check if the entry already exists within the North East sheet and if it does to do nothing and move onto the next row. I am unsure how to do this as im a total vba novice. Any help would be appreciated.

thanks

```
Sub Contain_Copy()
Dim ranger As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim FromSheet As Worksheet, ToSheet As Worksheet

Set FromSheet = Sheets("Master")
Set ToSheet = Sheets("NE")
lastrow = FromSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

For ranger = 2 To lastrow
    If InStr(1, FromSheet.Cells(ranger, "G"), "North East") > 0 Then
        FromSheet.Cells(ranger, "G").EntireRow.Copy _
        Destination:=ToSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    End If
Next ranger
End Sub
```

Comment: How do you check if the entry already exists - is there a particular cell to check or cells?

Comment: It's a bit of a cheat, but how about just running a *remove duplicates* on the destination sheet once it's finished running the loop?

Comment: @SJR each row has a unique identifier in column A, so ideally is that identifer already exists in the NE sheet it does not need to copy from the master sheet. I suppose a way around would be to copy and paste to the same row in the other worksheet that way it would only paste over itself. Is that possible?

Comment: What's your question?  Is your code throwing errors or is the output not as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach (though CLR's is arguably more efficient) using Match to check first whether the column A value already exists in column A of the NE sheet.

```
Sub Contain_Copy()

Dim ranger As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim FromSheet As Worksheet, ToSheet As Worksheet, v As Variant

Set FromSheet = Sheets("Master")
Set ToSheet = Sheets("NE")
lastrow = FromSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

For ranger = 2 To lastrow
    If InStr(1, FromSheet.Cells(ranger, "G"), "North East") > 0 Then
        v = Application.Match(FromSheet.Cells(ranger, "A"), ToSheet.Columns(1), 0)
        If IsError(v) Then
            FromSheet.Cells(ranger, "G").EntireRow.Copy _
            Destination:=ToSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    End If
Next ranger

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, this stops after copying the first row though

Comment: Got it to work, nothing wrong with your code just my ability to copy and paste. Thank you for all your help this works perfectly.

Comment: My pleasure. Perhaps you'd be so kind as to accept the answer (and upvote any other answers which may have helped).

Answer (score 0):

you could use `Find()` on `ToSheet` column "A" to check for current `FromSheet` column A cell value:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Contain_Copy()
    Dim ranger As Long
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim FromSheet As Worksheet, ToSheet As Worksheet

    Set FromSheet = Sheets("Master")
    Set ToSheet = Sheets("NE")
    lastrow = FromSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

    For ranger = 2 To lastrow
        If InStr(1, FromSheet.Cells(ranger, "G"), "North East") > 0 Then
            If Intersect(ToSheet.UsedRange, ToSheet.Columns(1)).Find(what:=FromSheet.Cells(ranger, "A").Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then _
                FromSheet.Cells(ranger, "G").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=ToSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next ranger
End Sub
```

you can also use `With ... End With` block and reduce accesses to `FromSheet` object

```
Sub Contain_Copy()
    Dim ranger As Long
    Dim ToSheet As Worksheet

    Set ToSheet = Sheets("NE")

    With Sheets("Master") ' reference "Master" sheet
        For ranger = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
            If InStr(1, .Cells(ranger, "G"), "North East") > 0 Then
                If Intersect(ToSheet.UsedRange, ToSheet.Columns(1)).Find(what:=.Cells(ranger, "A").Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then _
                    .Cells(ranger, "G").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=ToSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            End If
        Next ranger
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @RobS, any feedback?